# Apache camel hazelcast5 integration

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

We need to ugrade hazelcast4 to Hazelcast5 and we are using Camel connectors.Does Apache Camel connector supports the Hazelcast5.any answer or reply or link will be helpful

Comment: Hazelcast 5 is supported in Apache Camel starting from `3.16.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been updated from 3.16.0 ahead. 3.16.0 has been released last week: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/ab07cb5583874ca5fffbcf93d1929522359f77a5